# STRING to DATETIME Conversion in BIGQUERY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, date-conversion

How to convert '29-JUN-2022 05:56:31:653000000 AM' the string value into BIGQUERY DATETIME/TIMESTAMP.

I was to PARSE it when millisecond part had . instead of : .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was to PARSE it when millisecond part had . instead of : .

So, I think you can parse it after converting **last colon(:)** to **period(.)**.
Consider below regular expression to replace it.

```sql
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP(
         '%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%E*S %p',
         REGEXP_REPLACE('29-JUN-2022 05:56:31:653000000 AM', r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(\d+)', r'\1.\2')
       ) parsed_ts;
```

output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider

```
select parse_timestamp(
  '%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%E*S %p', 
  replace('29-JUN-2022 05:56:31:653000000 AM', ':', '.')
)
```

with output

[image]